# How to retrieve only one record from a list in props? (Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, react-props

My problem is the following:

I have a list with map that searches the DB and shows in a table.
The user has the option to click to check the details of the record.
A modal opens and shows these details.

But, in the modal, it search brings the list of all records instead of being only the one chosen by the user.

I already tried to use `stopPropagation` inside my button function but, even so it continues.

**useState modal**

```
const [isModalTraineeDetailsVisible, setModalTraineeDetailsVisible] = useState(false);
```

**Function to select the person's id in the table**

```
  const traineeSelectById = (e, listTrainee) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setModalTraineeDetailsVisible(true);
```

**Table showing the map and button with their functions**

```
 // Creating a map with date from listTraineeData, commes to the API BDD
                listTraineeData.map((listTrainee) => (
                  <StyledTableRow key={listTrainee.id}>
                    <StyledTableCell>{listTrainee.first_name}</StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell>{listTrainee.last_name}</StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell>{listTrainee.num_soci}</StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell>{listTrainee.addresse1}</StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell>{listTrainee.active}</StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell>
                      <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        size="small"
                        onClick={(e) =>
                          traineeSelectById(listTrainee)
                        }
                      >
                        {" "}
                        Details modal
                      </Button>
                      {isModalTraineeDetailsVisible ? (
                        <ModalTraineeDetails
                          data={listTrainee}
                          onClose={() => setModalTraineeDetailsVisible(false)}
                        >
                          <h2>Modal Details Trainee</h2>
                        </ModalTraineeDetails>
                      ) : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you map all items on `isModalTraineeDetailsVisible`, so if it false, will hide all items, and if it is true it will show all items, You should use an array instead and map with the index.

Also, You don't need to use `e.stopPropagation`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that.
I use only one stopPropagation. I tried putting it on the button to see what it would do.
So I always comment one of the two.
Please disregard that, I will edit my question and remove it.
Because this is how I put it in the code

Comment: Ok, never mind.

Comment: I update the answer too.

Comment: Please, I'm new to React.
Could you give me an example?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I investigate your problem. 
Definitely, the example is not the best. 
Try something like this

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [selectedTrainee, setSelectedTrainee] = useState()
  const trainees = [
    {
      id: '1',
      first_name: 'Chris',
      last_name: 'Ch'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      first_name: 'Paul',
      last_name: 'Pa'
    }
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Details</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          {trainees.map(trainee => {
            return (
              <tr key={trainee.id}>
                <td>{trainee.first_name}</td>
                <td>{trainee.last_name}</td>
                <td>
                  <button onClick={() => setSelectedTrainee(trainee)}>+</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>

      {selectedTrainee && (
        <Modal
          trainee={selectedTrainee}
          onClose={() => setSelectedTrainee(undefined)}
        >
          <h2>Modal Details Trainee</h2>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

function Modal(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(props.trainee)}</pre>

      <button
        onClick={props.onClose}
      >
        Close
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

PS. You should be more careful about naming.

What I did here? 
Firstly, I restructured your state. 
You only need information about selectedTrainee. 
Once you save the single trainee you can open the modal pretty easly.